# JVM failure - fail over

Tags: jvm, high-availability

I have read on high availability and scalability for J2EE apps. What I could not find is there any patterns on HA (resilience) that we can adopt to mitigate JVM failures.

Let me give an example.

A service is performing some business logic , writing or reading to/from DB and so on and there is a JVM crash. The reasons could be from pulling the power cord to kill the java process etc etc..

How do we do failover for the transactions that were the victims of such unexpected?

Thanks a lot for giving me the insight into your experience and approaches.

Regards
Sandeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [HA-JDBC](http://ha-jdbc.sourceforge.net/) a *"JDBC proxy that provides light-weight, transparent, fault tolerant clustering capability to any underlying JDBC driver."*  It utilizes the group membership awareness capabilities of [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org).